# Memcached inconsistency in values for maxbytes and limit_maxbytes

Tags: redhat, memcached

I'm using Memcached on RHEL/CentOS 5/6 and found that memory size inconsistency between limit_maxbytes and maxbytes taken from "stats" and "stats settings" respectively.

I have compiled memcached-1.4.15 from the source and set the limit_maxbytes value to 5GB but maxbytes shows only 904MB.

```
# ./memcached -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -m 5000 -u nobody -vv

# echo "stats " | nc 127.0.0.1 11211 | grep limit_maxbytes
STAT limit_maxbytes 5242880000

# echo "stats settings" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211 | grep maxbytes
STAT maxbytes 947912704
```

Eviction happens when it hits the maxbytes value and do not grow. Any reason for this behavior..?

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

# uname -rop
2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# file memcached
memcached: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked    (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

I have 48GB installed on this box. Note that I have used binary packages as well but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

On my Memcached box it works fine (1.4.5-1), but I think this is related to this bug:  http://code.google.com/p/memcached/issues/detail?id=319

Comment: I tried memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.x86_64.rpm as I can't find the tar.gz but still the same. This is Redhat v6/64bit box.